# CSS: On-mouse-over functionality from plot covered by a 'sheen' layer

Tags: css

I have a javascript plot on my page with "data point highlighter" functionality: when the mouse hovers over the point, you can see the coordinates popup. I also want to place a semi-transparent "sheen" image layer over the plot to make it look glossy. I can achieve this with the z-index, but the on-mouse-over functionality of the js plot stops working. Is there a way to have the sheen layer on top and still have the on-mouse-over of the layer below (the plot layer)? Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do that easily, apart from splitting apart the plot image and the area that reacts to the mouseover, and placing the latter above the sheen - which may be bothersome to do.

If it's semi-transparent, though, would it be an option to do the whole thing the other way round? Placing the "sheen" below the plot, and making the *plot* semi-transparent?

Comment: It's an idea, but I don't think it's workable - it would also change the look compared with the other plots that have a sheen, but don't need the on-mouse-over functionality. I'm thinking it's either lose the sheen or live without the point info.

Comment: Are we saying this can't be done at the moment? I don't know Pekka's css credentials, but your stacko credentials are pretty impressive, so I'm guessing this question is done. If there are no more responses, I'll answer it with "not possible".

Comment: @jjn If the plot image is the area the mouse movement needs to be caught on, I'd say with pure CSS, it's impossible. I can't even think of a crazy workaround. If you can somehow separate the image from the area catching the movement, you can probably get the area catching the movement on top of everything else (maybe even with pure CSS using `z-index`). But I assume that requires a total rewrite of your plotting tool. You could try adding some source code from the plot tool and looking whether somebody has an idea how to rewrite it as a last resort. Otherwise, close it as "not possible".

Comment: thanks for the effort - I appreciate it. If there are influential CSS guys watching: a visual-index (z-index) and active-index (what I'm looking for) would be useful!

I'm going to give up on this one and do without.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Shame.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe it is possible, but it's a bit of a messy workaround, and, in essence, involves capturing mouse/cursor position x/y location and mapping that to the plot layer -- not the easiest or optimal task, let alone completely inefficient.  I realize this is an older question, but thought I'd point this out for future users.

**Update:** Firefox has a CSS property geared toward this in the 3.6: http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/pointer-events/